# Fitnesse plugin in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, fitnesse

I'm trying to configure Fitness in Jenkins but have got stuck on the following sentence in the wiki: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fitnesse+Plugin:

> Project settings in build step

When I open the Jenkins configuration I don't find any Fitnesse-settings at all.
When I open the Project configuraiton the only thing that is fitnesse-related is "Publish Fitnesse results report"

So, how and where do I set the url to my Fitnesse-server in my Jenkins configuration? Or is this something that I should do in the Maven .pom?

Jenkins 1.406
Fitnesse-plugin 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Fitnesse plugin is installed properly, "Run Fitnesse Tests" should appear as one of the options under the "Add Build Step" button (along with "Execute Shell", "Execute Windows Batch Command" etc).

Comment: It took a little searching before I realized that I needed to check the "Run buildstep before SCM runs"-checkbox to see the Add Build Step button.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to figure this out too. However, after reading the manual **CAREFULLY** and playing around for a while I got it to work just like I knew it had to.

You need to include the jenkins FitNesse plug in **twice** in the job configuration:

- The first time is to execute the tests
- The second time gathers the results

**Test execution:**

Configure the first call to the plug-in under "Add post-build step", with the information to the FitNesse server and the tests to be executed. I put the test results in the workspace and clean the workspace down between builds.

[image: Add post-build step]

**Gather Results:**

This is the step where the results are evaluated and the success or failure of the job is checked. It also puts the link to the tests into the job overview.

Configure the second step under "Add post-build action" and include the test result (or results - ant type wild carding is allowd) you want to evaluate:

[image: Add post-build action]

Now, when running a build, the FitNesse results are evaluated and the job is passed or failed based on the FitNesse results in addition to the other test steps you have.

You can see the results on the build summary:

[image]